# What is the name of the typeface used in the Soldsie logo?

Tags: font-identification, serif

Can anybody please tell me what typeface this is in the image? I need it for a logo that I'm going to be making.

[image]

Comment: See this [link](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) from you can pass image and get font >http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [American Typewriter Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/itc-american-typewriter/):

[image]

It's obviously been slightly modified and then tracked tightly (which is somewhat silly if you want to be pedantic about it as the typeface is based on common typewriter fonts which were traditionally monospaced and never capable of being tracked like this).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see yourself the logo can be downloaded from the Soldsie [internet site](http://new.soldsie.com/press/) including the soldie's letter S:

[image]

In other words, they give you an image instead just embedding the font in the site.

From this fact I suppose that the logo was custom made and you probably cannot find 100% match between the logo and the font used as an inspiration.